# react-native-pusher-push-notifications application crash when receive notification

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I'm using react-native-pusher-push-notifications to get notification in react native android app 
application registers correctly and when i send notification from pusher beams dashboard application crash and close

i'm using :

```
compile project(':react-native-pusher-push-notifications')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.pusher:push-notifications-android'
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your current implementation? Are you sure that you went through all Android steps from `react-native-pusher-push-notifications` package here? Here is the link to it: https://github.com/b8ne/react-native-pusher-push-notifications#android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!

Its a problem with firebase messaging version, see this, it fixed the crash

https://github.com/b8ne/react-native-pusher-push-notifications/issues/41

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but it might help. The same thing is happening to me, when i send a test push notification to the device (registered already), the app crashes, so it recives the notification but in that process, it crashes.

The main difference here is that i'm not using the react-native-pusher-push-notifications library. I did it just as pusher told me to do it, in MainApplication.java for example:

```
import com.pusher.pushnotifications.PushNotifications;



PushNotifications.start(getApplicationContext(), "xxxxxx-ccccc-4234-8ba8-cccsadadasdas");
  PushNotifications.addDeviceInterest("hello");
```

So i think it might be something to do with libraries versions and so, but not with the package you are using (by the way, i haven't solved the problem yet, i was lucking for the solution and your question appeared).

Comment: My problem was that I used another package (react-native-push-notification) in my project and then I tried to use (react-native-pusher-push-notification) so my app crashed . I solved it by removing the old package configurations from  AndroidManifest.xml and change my firebase messaging version